# which is suitable DB to store large amount of Images (for Online shopping carts)

Tags: mysql, image, nosql, filesystems, cloud

which is suitable DB  to store large amount of  Images (for Online shopping carts)

I would like to know what is the best solution for storing large amount of images like Online shopping carts Ebay,Flipkart etc

It seems that storing in Cloud is better then storing inside a database

what about using a NoSql DataBases like MongoDB etc for storing Images

What is the best solution?

Thanks in Advance

Sandy

Comment: Typically people store images as images on a file system and point to the image locations from a database. If you really need to store binary data in a database something like BerkeleyDB would be fine. MongoDB has a 16MB per key/value pair limit, however you could program your way past that limitation.

Comment: thanks Claris for suggestion......

Answer (score 1):

Best solution is always to use a cloud storage system as Amazon S3, Google Drive, Dropbox. [Here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/tomcat7-hibernate-s3-clickstart) you can see an application example, which shows you how to upload an image to Amazon S3. You can launch it directly to the PaaS provider to see if it is what you are looking for.

A similar Spring application example for online shopping is the Bees Shop ClickStart, which shows you how to do it also with Amazon S3.